# converting a raw pointer to shared pointer.Are shared pointers thread safe?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following setter and getter which gives me raw pointers.
These could be accessed from different threads  as well.I want to make m_pObj a shared pointer- - std::shared_ptr<(IMyInterface> m_pObj;

Code was like this.
If m_obj is not null i have to release and assign the new pointer in SetPointer

```
void MyClass::SetPointer(IMyInterface* pObj)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs1)
    if (NULL != m_pObj)//Member variable to hold the incoming pointer
    {
        m_pObj>Release();
        m_pObj= NULL;
    }

    m_pObj= pObj;

    if (NULL != m_pObj )
    {
        m_pObj->AddRef();
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs1)
}

IMyInterface* MyClass::GetPointer()
{ 
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs1)
    if (NULL != m_pObj)
    {
        m_pObj->AddRef();
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs1)
    return m_pObj;
}

void MyClass::SetPointer(IMyInterface* pObj)
{
    if (NULL != m_pObj)
    {
        m_pObj->Release();
        m_pObj= NULL;
    }
    m_pObj = std::shared_ptr<IMyInterface>(pObj));
}
```

While accessing the getter in another class it should increase the reference count as well,for shared pointer,I think I just have to assign it to the local shared pointer rit?Would it automatically increase the reference count?

```
std::shared_ptr<IMyInterface> MyClass::GetPointer()
{
    return m_pObj;
};
```

accessing from other place

```
std::shared_ptr<IMyInterface> pObj1 = GetPointer();//hope it would increase th reference count
```

Both the functions could be accessed from different threads-its possible the the in other places the getter is called and before I do addref the setter called from different thread and released it,so was the CS for.In this case is it needed?Is the modified one OK?

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

So if you use `const` methods of `shared_ptr` you are on the safe side. But in your case you write concurrently (CopyConstructor in getter and `reset` in setter) to the same instance of `std::shared_ptr` (namely the member variable `m_pObj`) and this leads to undefined behaviour.

Also, using methods of the underlying object by different threads (for example your `IMyInterface::Release`-method) leads also to data races.

And so you will need a CS for synchronization.

Comment: How can I avoid Release.Can I directly assign?would it release the previous object when new pointer is assigned?Any help in making this thread safe without CS ?